# Why won't the user input go into the database?

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite, debugging

As of now, my database works fine.  I can manually create dummy email address' via `Terminal` and they'll appear with no problems.

This time, I want to the user input to go into the database.  I feel that I'm pretty close with the code I have now.  But I keep getting this `error` in `Chrome`:

Here's the `error`:

```
 TypeError at /content/content/
'name' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/content/content/
Django Version: 1.11.3
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
'name' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

Here's `basic.html`:

```
{% extends "personal/header.html" %}

{% block content %}
<style type="text/css">
    h1 {
        color: #2e6da4;
        font-family: Chalkboard;
    }

    .text {
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>

    {% for c in content %}
        <h1>{{c}}</h1>
    {% endfor %}

    <div class="form-group">
        <form method="POST" action="content/">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="text" name="textfield">

            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
        </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Here's `views.py`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Email
from django.core.exceptions import *

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'personal/home.html')

def contact(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render(request, 'personal/basic.html', {'content': ['If you would like more information, leave your email.']})

    elif request.method == "POST":
        email = Email(name=request.POST.get("textfield"))
        email.save()
        return render(request, 'basic.html')

def search(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        search_id = request.POST.get(name = search_id)
        try:
            user = Email.objects.get(name=search_id)
            # do something with user
            html = ("<H1>%s</H1>", user)
            return HttpResponse(html)
        except Email.DoesNotExist:
            return HttpResponse("no such user")
        else:
            return render(request, 'basic.html')
```

Here's `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^content/', views.contact, name='content'),
]
```

Here's `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models

class Email(models.Model):
    email = models.CharField(max_length=140)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

Comment: What do you expect this to do? `request.POST.get(name = search_id)`

Comment: Like the error says, `name` is not a valid keyword for that class. Does the model actually have a name field? You should show the model.

Comment: please, show your `class Email`

Comment: @BearBrown model posted.

Comment: @DanielRoseman model posted

Comment: Well, as we said, you clearly don't have a field called `name`. So why are you trying to pass one when you create the model?

Comment: @DanielRoseman well sorry, I'm not an expert like you.  I'm sure you've never ever made a mistake in your life.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need replace, because in your model no filed `name` but has field `email`

```
email = Email(name=request.POST.get("textfield"))
```

to

```
email = Email(email=request.POST.get("textfield"))
#             ^^^^^
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I tried that, but now I get an error that says `TemplateDoesNotExist at /content/content/`.

Comment: I think you need replace `return render(request, 'basic.html')` to the `return render(request, 'personal/basic.html')`

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked!  Now I understand the errors I made.  Thanks again man!

Comment: @hop38 Please don't forget to vote for Bear's work since the answer is useful to you.

Comment: @hop38 My mistake not noticing you are quite new to StackOverflow. Welcome here and enjoy :D